# Problems with Directions API in Google Maps V3 and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, maps

I'm trying to get Google Maps Directions API working with jQuery, and
I have the following code..

http://pastebin.com/6jcGt706

Where #end is a select list in the HTML.. I'm Using jQuery 1.4.. I'm
not sure as to what is going wrong.. Can you please help me with
this...

Would appreciate if any one could help me fix the problem with this..

Thanks!

Comment: This is what I want to achieve http://mobspot.in/gpsdemo.html, here's the page I've coded up http://mobspot.in/turnbyturn.html #jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Check Firebug or Web Inpector Console for any errors thrown. Chances are you just need to change this line:

```
var end = $("#end option:selected");
```

to:

```
var end = $("#end").val();
```